# Wingpanel going transparent on its own

Tags: wingpanel, updates, themes

I prefer wingpanel not being transparent, and have set org.pantheon.desktop.wingpanel.use-transparency to false.  Several times recently, and just after running updates today, my wingpanel became transparent.

Using dconf Editor to check the setting, it still showed false (not transparent).  Once I checked the box and then unchecked it, wingpanel was again opaque.

Is anyone else having this issue?  Is it update related or was that a conincidence?  Is there a different setting I should be using?  Thanks.